# mvc dbcontext not working on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm creating a processor class and running inside worker role.
and inside the processor i create the reporsitory to do CRUD operation to my DB.

I have 2 repositories, product and productsize, dbcontext is created in product repo and pass to product size.

everything is running fine on my local machine, however when i deploy to Azure, the system throw me this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

processor.cs

```
  public class Processor : IDisposable
    {

        private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

        public Processor()
            : this(new ProductRepository())
        {

        }

        public Processor(
            IProductRepository productRepository

            )
        {
            _productRepository = productRepository;
        }

        public void Run(){ _productRepository.someoperation;}

        public void Dispose()
        {

            _productRepository.Dispose();

        }
```

productrepository.cs

```
        public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
        {


        private static readonly DbContext_context = new DbContext();

        private readonly IProductSizeRepository _productSizeRepository;


        public ProductRepository()
            : this(
            new ProductSizeRepository(_context))
        {

        }

        public ProductRepository(
            IProductSizeRepository productSizeRepository
           )
        {

            _pictureRepository = pictureRepository;

        }

   public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();


            _productSizeRepository.Dispose();


        }
```

in the workerrole.cs while loop
    using (var runner = new Processor())
                {
                     runner.Run();
                }

Comment: Is you database SQL Server?

Comment: Are you still using SQL Server Compact Edition (SCSE) in the cloud??

Comment: How do you pass the connection string to your DbContext?

Comment: Have you some using statement arround your `_context` somewhere in the code?

Comment: We miss the dispose method of `ProductRepository`

Comment: Or around any ProductRepository if the dispose dispose the context? see [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801266/why-is-dbcontext-disposed-before-the-foreach-loop)

Comment: sorry, update the question

Answer (score 0):

need to set all of the reference copy to local=true

and initiate dbcontext in the code instead of in the constructor